# What replaces the deprecated any_to_string function?

Tags: f#

I guess it's now `Object.ToString()` but I'm unsure... Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the only way to get any_to_string functionality is with the "%A" formatter. The warning tells you this.

`let any_to_string = sprintf "%A"`

This does not invoke .ToString(). For 'simple' types like lists the .ToString() already yields a good representation. But when using your own custom types, the %A formatter is much more useful. For instance, in case of tree structures it walks along the tree.

If you do want to invoke .ToString() on an object, you can use the '%O' formatter.

Example:

```
type Tree = Node of Tree * Tree | Leaf
let myTree = Node(Node(Leaf,Leaf),Node(Leaf,Node(Leaf,Leaf)))
```

and in FSI:

```
> myTree.ToString();;
val it : string = "FSI_0002+Tree+Node"
> sprintf "%O" myTree;;
val it : string = "FSI_0002+Tree+Node"
> sprintf "%A" myTree;;
val it : string = "Node (Node (Leaf,Leaf),Node (Leaf,Node (Leaf,Leaf)))"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use sprintf:

```
let a = [1;2;3]
let b = sprintf "%A" a
```

Comment: Is it the only other possible alternative?

Comment: I think so.  (more chars to reach comment minimum)

Answer (score 1):

What about the `string` function?

```
> string [1..3];;
val it : string = "[1; 2; 3]"
```